# Restore Backup can this still be done after choosing setup as new?

Tags: itunes, ipad, restore

I want to Restore my iPad, I have already created a backup on my Windows 7 PC using iTunes. When I restore my Ipad, as far as I remember from some tutorials online, you will have to choose to restore from iCloud/iTunes or "As New" (Something like this). So when I select "As New" and later after the restoration, I connect my iPad to my Windows 7 machine with iTunes and choose "restore iPad", will it give me back my backup data? Even if I chose "As New" above?

Comment: Uhhhh..... No..

Comment: please tell me why

Comment: Because you choose to set it up as a new device, therefor separate from all of your data

Answer (score 1):

No, because you set it up as a new device instead of restoring from an "existing device".

Therefore, it will treat it as such, and not move data from your backup to your iPad,

You can still move that data over once you're done setting up the iPad, by using the restore button in iTunes. But you will loose the setup and any changes done before the restore.